# How to put enable/disable lock, Pin, Pattern and Fingerprint locks for application

Tags: javascript, android, switch-statement, locking

I like to put enable/disable lock, pin, pattern, fingerprint locks in my application to lock my app.
if lock is enable, user have to select any lock option means pin, pattern, fingerprint.
fingerprint is switch preference if it is enable then fingerprint lock activates.
Lock is enable then app is locked with any lock types means Pin, Pattern, Fingerprint.

Comment: You should make an attempt first and then ask on SO for help :)

Comment: First, try something and come up with questions about your specific sample code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

There is no default setup for that. You need to implement your own (or use libraries) security check.